# How to resize UIPageViewController in landscape

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, ios7, uipageviewcontroller

I am having an issue with resizing `UIPageViewController` in landscape mode.

Here is my scenario:

I have a `UIViewController` which has a `scrollview` in it.
I added a `UIPageViewController` to the `scrollview` programmatically and it is displaying all my view controllers in each page correctly.
When i change the device orientation to landscape i am correctly changing the content size of the `scrollview` but the `PageViewController` is displaying only up to half of its contents. Can you please help me with this one.

Thanks,
Anand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are either not getting the correct orientation of your device or trying to set it in the `viewDidLoad` function. The following code should correctly set your page view controller's frame to current orientation.

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    CGRect screenFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])) {
        screenFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenFrame.size.height, screenFrame.size.width);
    }

    //Please don't forget to replace _myPageViewController with your variable 
    _myPageViewController.frame = screenFrame;
}
```

> Please note that code is getting called from `viewWillLayoutSubviews`
>   function.

Comment: I deleted the scrollview in my app and replaced it with a view. 

So currently my viewcontroller has a uisegmented control and a uiview. The uiview has a pageviewcontroller. I still cant resize the pageview controller in landscape mode.
Please help me. <br />and i am modified your viewWIllLayoutSubViews as follows to fit my needs: 
    
    self.subView.frame = screenFrame;
    [[self.pageController view] setFrame:[[self subView] bounds]];

Comment: I modified your viewWillLayoutSubViews to fit my purpose and now it works. Thank you so much.

Comment: After breaking head for 3 hours.....finally got the correct solution.Thanks you so much :)